# Calling angular ngClick actions from appended content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please reference Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/acPGl5k0ECO9yFAYgfIW?p=preview as it probably demonstrates better what I want to explain.

Using Angular, the goal is to click an element (in this case, when a form input takes focus) which causes a DIV to be appended to the page -- using `element.parent().append(template)`. Within that appended DIV is a button with an ngClick action that should fire when clicked.

The problem appears to be that the ngClick directive is never registered. Clicking it does nothing. Is this a case for using compile in the directive definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to `$compile` the element in this case. Inject the `$compile` service and then do this:

```
$x = angular.element(appendTemplate);
element.bind('focus', function() {
  element.parent().append($x);
});
$compile($x)(scope);
```

I am using angular.element to actually create dom nodes from the html string so that the `$compile` will be for the actual element that is on the page.

**[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/deipoOOHs9jYwsv58mZL?p=preview)**

However, it's worth noting that there are a lot of improvements that could be made to this code. For example, it would make sense for a scope function to be declared in a controller and passed to the directive. If the directive needs to make functionality, I would make it a locally scoped function and use it in the event binding, not attach it to scope. With that in mind, you may be able to refactor using `compile` rather than `link` so that the markup is automatically compiled.